# Is there an alternative to Messages?

Tags: messages

I'm having the problem of synced iMessages appearing out of order in Messages on my Macbook.  I've even had messages sent to wrong people.  I can't find any alternatives through Google.  Is there a replacement that will still sync with iMessages from my phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole iMessage system is entirely proprietary, and there are no 3rd party clients available to use instead of the official ones, on either iOS or OSX.  That's not to say it won't be reverse engineered in time, but I suspect that Apple will fix any issues way before anything like that happens.

I too get messages that appear out of order and occasionally ones that simply never show on one device or another, but *anecdotally* I only ever see this when devices are playing "catch up" with messages that I have already read elsewhere.

Comment: I, on other hand, have watched it happen in real time.  I'll have Messages up on my MacBook Pro while sending from my iPhone and will watch messages I sent from the phone appear on the computer in the wrong order or missing some words.  I use iMessage on three Macs and two iOS devices, and in my experience, the only thing I can count on iMessage doing reliably is not working.

Comment: I've just stopped using iMessage.